# Launch Android Application in Mobile when launcher is corrupted

Tags: android, android-launcher

Launcher application is manually deleted from the phone. Phone is in working condition. Able to list down the background tasks. Lock/Unlock screen and notification bars are working. Is there any way to launch an application without launcher in android phones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the Launcher app source code from android source and compile and flash in phone directly using Eclipse IDE or Android studio. This will give your launcher back. I did the same and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

If you have google's account on phone try install any Launcher from browser in another PC by Google Play (you must login in Goggle Play in browser). And wait time for automatic install this app on your device (in my case around 1 day).

Also you can install any app to device from Google Play. If this app can start on boot device wait this app after reboot device.

Comment: Google play just installs the app. I was not able to start the same.